# How to go to a secured url after payment via stripe?

Tags: url, dns, stripe-payments

im trying to create a paywall sort of modus.
I have a stripe account, and i want people to pay via stripe, and them getting redirect to a url which can only be accessed after payment. I found I can redirect to an own URL after payment confirmation, but i dont want visitors to be able to simply copy and paste this url thus getting access to the page.
How can i setup stripe to fulfill this?
Many thanks in advance!

I found the posibility to redirect to a custom 'thank-you' page, but this url is always accessable and people can see the used url.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for does not exist on Stripe. Stripe's Checkout or Payment Links (or Payment Element) handle accepting a payment and redirecting your customer to the success page.

You'll have to build authentication on your end where you store which customer has access to which resource behind paywall and check that they have paid for the page they are trying to access.